# Change uri parameters passing

Tags: mod-rewrite

Link example jumppage support:
http://server-address/index.php?param1={value1},{value2},{value3}

-Above is comma separated

Link example our website support:
http://server-address/index.php?param1={value1}&param2={value2}&param3={value3}

How can i reformat the initial paramaters are passed according to our standard?

Thanx!

Comment: you want to rewrite the 2nd URL to look like the 1st URL ?

Comment: No input is the first one and output should be the second one. So rewrite the 1st to second, thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase   /

 RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^param1=(.*?),(.*?),(.*)$
 RewriteRule   ^index\.php$    index.php?param1=%1&param2=%2&param3=%3  [L]
```

Note this does an internal redirect rather than a 301 or 302.  Also not that is the comma separated list contain a variable number of items *or* there are other parameters, this can also be handled but the rules get a lot more complicated.